# How to create two bins from 4 levels in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

One of my columns in `pandas` dataframe looks like following. I would like to bin my "Daughter" column such that row with 0 will receive label of "None" and rows containing 1,2,3,4 will receive labels of "Some".

**Current Dataset that contains column**

```
Daughter
0
0
1
2
4
3
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Daughter Daugther_fact
0         None
0         None
1         Some
2         Some
4         Some
3         Some
```

I new newbie to python. I know I have to use `pd.cut` to assign my labels, but I am not sure how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
pd.cut(df.Daughter,[-np.inf,0,np.inf],labels=['None','some'])
Out[35]: 
0    None
1    None
2    some
3    some
4    some
5    some
Name: Daughter, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [None < some]
```

Answer (score 4):

Import `pandas` and `numpy` first.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Could you please try following.

```
m=df['Daughter']!=0
df['Daughter_fact']=np.where(m,"Some","None")
df
```

When we print `df` then output will be as follows.

```
  Daughter  Daughter_fact
0  0         None 
1  0         None 
2  1         Some 
3  2         Some 
4  4         Some 
5  3         Some
```